# How to configure gunicorn service file

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn, digital-ocean

I'm deploying a django project on digital ocean. My project has the following structure:

```
$/
    flo-log/
        logistics/
            settings.py
            wsgi.py
            ...
    manage.py
    ...
```

My project gunicorn fille is shown below:

```
Description=gunicorn daemon
Requires=gunicorn.socket
After=network.target

[Service]
User=flolog
Group=flolog
WorkingDirectory=/home/flolog/flo-log/logistics
ExecStart=/home/flolog/flologenv/bin/gunicorn \
          --access-logfile - \
          --workers 3 \
          --bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock \
          logistics.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I created a user with sudo privilege. Whenever I run `sudo systemctl status gunicorn` I encountered `ModuleNotFoundError: no module named logistics`.
And from the details of the error, it's due to the **logistics.wsgi: application component of gunicorn service file**

The error stated that there's no module called `logistics` however,I have a directory called logistics which contains the wsgi file. Please how do I fix this error? Why is it that they are telling me `logistics`bis not a directory. Better still, how do I set `myproject.wsgi` section of gunicorn service file properly based on my project structure

Answer (score 0):

I would say just look at your project structure. Remove the flo-log first folder and have Logistics and manage.py inside the home directory of your server as well as your virtual env. The project file "Logistics" should be in the same folder as manage.py inside home.

Hope that helps.